# TP-Link router with quantenna firmware hacked my network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, repeater

I have an TP-Link TL-WA701ND wich i used as universal repeater, a few months back i noticed that the repeater failed to repeat the wifi signal, so i entered the router configuration and i noticed that it was automatically updated to some firmware by "Quantenna Wireless Adapter v36.7.0.31", so i restarted to the factory settings using the rear button on the router, however every time i configured it, the repeater would update itself to the quantenna firmware.

After a lot of tries i gave up and decided to just turn it off,  but to my surprise, even when the repeater is disconnected from the source power it can be accessed from the browser, using the custom local ip that i assigned to it.

I even accessed my internet provider router and deleted the repeater, but for some reason it continues to be accesible within the local network. I tried to do a traceroute to the repeater´s custom local ip but it didn't show any usable information, so i believe that the repeater is using a possible spoofed ip. And now i dont know what to do to delete it from my network. Any help is appreciated.

[I`ve attached a photo showing the repeater disconnected and its management page working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgLQs.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible that it can be accessed when it's disconnected from power source as it has not battery in it. You must be connecting to some other router.

Comment: As simplistic an answer this is, it is absolutely correct. @insomnium098 you are definitely connected to a different device. Quantenna is a WiFi product company, making chipsets and cloud-based solutions. Disable your WiFi and connect via hard wired connection to the TP-Link router in question after a factory reset and I am sure you will get to the TP-Link firmware configuration page. This could be someone near you is repeating your signal in an attempt to use your Internet or hack your network through, I would immediately factory default your router and change your WiFi password and SSID.

Comment: Oh, and change the passwords, and usernames if possible, on your devices... leaving them admin/admin is just asking for problems too.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys, after a lot of research i figured out. It seems that the ip that i was assigning to my repeater (192.168.1.200) is the factory ip of the 5 ghz chip of my router (Alcatel-Lucent G-240W-B), so i just assigned a different ip to the repeater and the problem was solved.